# Link to category using tinymce

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I use the tinymce 'link to existing content' button a lot for linking to posts but would like to know if it's possible to have categories show up in the list as well?

We need to link to categories a fair bit and doing it manually is a bit of a pain.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a built in behavior for this feature. It would have to be custom coded.